# Ant design time picker autoselect time

Tags: reactjs, antd

When you have clear TimePicker from antD library and try to select time, for example clicked on hours and then minutes and seconds select automatically, how to avoid that? I couldn't find any solution on the documentation or in web. This "bug" is even on their page: https://ant.design/components/time-picker

I see there defaultOpenValue prop but it is deprecated.

This is my usage of it:

```
<Form.Item
              label={
                <label className={styles.hourLabel}>
                  Working hours{' '}
                  {
                    <Tooltip title="Specify your everyday work hours to help others see when they can usually reach you">
                      <InfoCircleOutlined />
                    </Tooltip>
                  }
                </label>
              }
              name="work_time_range"
              rules={[
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: 'Please select start and end time.',
                },
              ]}
              initialValue={[
                user.work_start_time &&
                  dayjs(
                    timeStrToLocal(user.work_start_time, user.timezone),
                    'HH:mm'
                  ),
                user.work_end_time &&
                  dayjs(
                    timeStrToLocal(user.work_end_time, user.timezone),
                    'HH:mm'
                  ),
              ]}
            >
              <TimePicker.RangePicker
                format="HH:mm"
                placeholder={['Start', 'End']}
                allowClear={false}
              />
            </Form.Item>
```

Comment: I couldn't find any solution